# How to get the exact time of a button click?

Tags: javascript, datetime, cypress

I am testing a button that downloads a file, and sets the filename to the current time of when that button was clicked. I am trying to validate that the downloaded file has the correct time in its filename.

This is where I'm at. It matches for the `HH:mm` but is off in `ss`

```
cy.get('download-button').click()

const date = new Date();
const exactTime = date.toLocaleTimeString('sv', {hour12: false, timeZone: Asia/Jakarta })
```

The above code returns `12:43:36`, but the expected is `12:43:38`

Comment: If I were you, I would just check that the filename's time is within a minute or so of the time of the button being clicked and call it a day. Is there any reason why you need centi-second precision?

Comment: @Flimm - no reason, I was just wondering if there is a way to get the exact time of a button click.

Comment: Can you show your assertion?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy - I used aliases and used them for my assertion: `cy.wrap(downloadTimestamp).should('eq', downloadedDocumentTitle)`.

Comment: Have you tried mocking the time with [`cy.clock()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock)?

Comment: @NickMcCurdy - I haven't tried `cy.clock()`. I'm not sure how to implement it on my test. I will try though.

Comment: cypress commands are async, so exactTime might be computed before your command of click is computed